# I want to call Comments.php file in sidebar.php file

Tags: php

I have comments.php file i need to call it in sidebar file so that comments shld be in sidebar. I use genesis theme.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't providing much detail here, but just looking at your question,  all you need is a

```
include("comments.php");
```

In you sidebar.

Comment: Tq:-) working well and good

Answer (score 1):

sidebar.php

```
<?php
require('comments.php');

?>
```

Comment: Tq :-) its working now

Comment: if it is working then please upvote my ans...